# Redirecting a single link from my site to a new one

Tags: redirects, youtube

I have a WordPress blog say `exampleblog.com` and I have a YouTube channel too. Basically, I want to put a custom link to subscribe to my channel like so `exampleblog.com/subscribe` to put in my YouTube description. I am using the `meta-refresh` method but found here that is not the best practice SEO-wise.

What kind of redirect should I use then? I read about all the `300` type of redirects and honestly all of them seem to suit me well.

Comment: It sounds like it should be an ordinary link? Why do you need a "redirect"? What's "YT description"?

Comment: I am just as confused.

Comment: By "YT description", I believe the OP meant the YouTube description for his channel. They need to clarify however why they'd think this was a redirect, and where the link is to (i.e., the link is to their YouTube channel from their blog site, or the link is to their blog site from their YouTube channel's description..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google provides a simple yet great solution to effortlessly embed a subscribe button on any website.**

1. Go to Google's **[Configure a Button](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button)** generator.
2. Enter Channel / User name
3. Style the button
4. Copy the code to be pasted on your website.

**Using a text link to redirect a user to a Youtube Channel, where the visitor is prompted to Subscribe. That code is as follows.**

```
https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=GoProCamera
```

replace "GoProCamera" with your own username and you're done.

**Retrieving your Youtube User Id and Channel Id.**

Youtube ID's are located in the " Overview > [Advanced](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) " section of your Youtube account.

---

**To address your other concerns.**

> I am using the meta-refresh method but found here that is not the best practice, SEO-wise.

The meta-refresh syntax should not be used in this case.

**What is meta-refresh good for?** How about I tell you how deceptive usage has caused concern for this method.

You visit a site, and 20 secs later, you are redirected to another page, and from there 3 pop ups appear. That can quickly annoy a user and the rest could be played out in your mind of all the ways to avoid using it improperly.

**301 redirects and similar methods will serve no purpose here.**

They are usually used where a site has changed a name for instance Http to Https. Not applicable here for any reason.

Comment: You sir are fantastic. You don't know how much you really helped me!

Comment: My pleasure, I am glad it worked at for you. Cheers